# How can I change the background operation priority dynamically using Dispatch or Operation queues.

Tags: ios, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, nsthread, nsoperationqueue

Here is the problem that I got. I have several tasks to complete in background when application is running. When I run these tasks in background by pushing them to concurrent dispatch queue it takes more then 10 seconds to complete all of them. They basically load data from disk and parse it and represent the result to the user. That is they are just cached results and hugely improve the user experience.

This cached results are used in a particular functionality inside the app, and when that functionality is not used immediately after opening the application, it is not a problem that it takes 10 seconds to load the data that supports that functionality, because when user decides to use it, that data will already be loaded.

But when user immediately enters that function in the app after opening it, it takes considerable time (from the point of view of the user) to load the data. Also the whole data is not needed at the same moment, but rather the piece of it at a given moment. 
That's why we need concurrently load the data, and if possible bring the results as soon as possible. That's why I decided to break the data into chunks, and when user requests the data, we should load the corresponding chunk by background thread and give that thread the highest priority. I'll explain what I mean.

Imagine there are 100 pieces of data and it takes more than 10 seconds to load them all.  Whenever user queries the data first time, the app determines which chunk of the data user needs and starts loading that chunk. After that part is loaded the remaining data will also be loaded in the background, in order to make later queries faster (without the lag of loading the cache). But here a problem occurs, when user decides to change the query immediately after he has already entered one, and that change occurs for instance on the 2nd second of data loading process (remember it takes more than 10 seconds to load the data  and we still have more than 8 seconds to complete the loading process), then in the extreme case user will receive his data waiting until all data will be loaded. That's way I need somehow manage the execution of the background tasks. That is, when user changes the input, I should change the priorities of execution, and give the thread that loads the corresponding chunk the highest priority without stopping it, so it will receive more processor time, and will finish sooner, and deliver results to the user faster, than it would if I have left the priorities the same. I know I can assign priorities to queues. But is there a way that I can change them dynamically while they are still executing?
Or do I need to implement custom thread management, in order to implement these behaviour? I really don't want to dive into thread management, and will be glad if it is possible to implement using only dispatch or operation queues.

I hope I've described the problem well. If not please comment bellow what is unclear, I'll explain.

Thank you so much for reading so far :) And special thanks to one who will provide an answer. And very special thanks to one, who will give me solution using dispatch or operation queues :)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid the only way to do that is to cancel running operation before starting new one.
You cannot remove it from queue until it's done or canceled.

As an improvement for your problem I would suggest to load things even user doesn't need them in background - so you can load them from cache after it's there.

You can create 2 NSOperationQueue with 2 different priorities and download things in background whenever user is idle on LowPriorityQueue. For important operations you can have high priority queue - which you will cancel each time search term changes.

On top of that you just need to cache results from both of those queues.

Comment: As for first suggestion, I've thought about it, but didn't think that it will be good idea, to spoil the loaded data.

Comment: As for second, I do load data even when user doesn't needs it. As I've said I start the loading process as soon as app starts. The only extreme case is that users starts search immediately after app starts, that is the part I want to make more responsive. But I think, yes only way is to cancel the job and restart. May be I will be able to set checkpoints in the loading process, so that when canceling not all work will be lost, and so I will be able to continue from last checkpoint.Thanks for the answer. i'll wait maybe somebody gives another suggestion. But hardly.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to move away from thinking about the priority at which the queues are running (which actually doesn't sound very important for the scenario you are describing) and more towards how you can use Dispatch I/O or an even simpler Dispatch source to control how the data is being read in.  As you say, it takes 10 seconds the load the data and if the user suddenly changes their query immediately after asking, you need to essentially stop reading the data for the previous request and do whatever needs to be done to fulfill the most recent query.  Using Dispatch I/O to chunk the data (asynchronously) and update the UI also asynchronously will allow you to change your mind mid-stream (using some sort of semaphore or cancellation flag) and either continue to trickle the data in (you don't say whether or not that data will remain useful if the user changes their mind or not), suspend the reading process, or cancel it altogether and start a new operation.  Eithe way, being able to suspend/resume a source and also have it fire callbacks for reasonably small chunks of data will certainly enable you to make decisions on a much more granular chunk of time than 8 seconds!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually the load is not the result query, it is rather the index that is being loaded from disk. So I need it even though user cancels query. So Both your answer and previous were actually the same. All I need is cancel the task and re run it. However I do need the data of the task. As On that data other queries will be based. Now I just need to determine how to chunk the data (search index in this case) so it is loaded in most efficient way.